# How to run a JavaScript function on a html page having a specific element with Webpack?

Tags: javascript, webpack

In the client side, I have structured my code like this:

```
client
├── js
│   ├── sidebarTemplate.js
│   └── scrollToTop.js
├── _view
│   ├── index.html
│   └── a.html
│   ├── b.html
│   └── c.html
├── index.js
```

In details: I have multiple html files placed in **view** folder, different custom JavaScript functions placed in **js** folder, and the **index.js** file works as the entry point for webpack setup.
The **view** folder has index.html, a.html, b.html, c.html files.
The **js** folder has **sidebarTemplate.js** file which is used to populate the sidebar of all html pages in the **view** folder, and **scrollToTop.js** file which is used when user want to get back to the top for only the pages that have button element.

In **index.js"** file, I place my Js functions:

```
//add the side bar for all html files
addSidebarTemplate();
//Load the page having the button element 
//if user click the button then run the function to going to the top of the page
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', toTheTop);
```

The function to populate the sidebar elements for every pages and it works perfectly fine to any page that I clicked on. However, When I tried to run the function to scroll to the top for example the page c.html. It did not work. Looking at the console, for the c.html page, there was no errors shown off, but for index.html, a.html and b.html pages, the error was "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null..."

I have tested my code by only working with c.html file, and toTheTop function by placing the in another folder and it worked. So, there's nothing wrong with my js functions.

My overall question is that How can I organize the index.js file so that when I call a function, the function only works for a specific html page not all of them. It would be great if you guys can give me some articles to fix the issue.
Thank a lot!

Comment: Why don't you load your scrollToTop.js file only in those html-s where they are used in fact? If you load it via a script tag with an id, you can wrap the event listener in your index.js into this: if(document.querySelector("#id")) {  } . So it registers the listener only if the JS script for it is present.

Comment: Thanks Máté. Do you mean that I should set up another entry point for the html file that i want to use my function? If so, I just wonder in the case that when I have many other html files? Sorry if I misunderstand, I am quite confused how to use webpack.

Comment: The structure you pasted is your client side which practically uses one single index.html file and the content in its body is replaced via Javascript. If you insist on using html files as templates, you should consider using a server-side template engine.

Comment: I will do that later with a JS framework but I just make some basic functions to understand how webpack work. With my file structure, Is that right that whatever the html file I click, webpack will run all of js functions that I passed in index.js to that html file?

Comment: Yes, that is true. That is why your JS files in the JS folder should not be loaded in index.js but they should be imported in the framework files where you will actually use them.

Comment: I will try. Thank for your help!

Comment: If you find my comments useful, could you please upvote at least one of them? Thank you!

Comment: I don't see any upvote button around your comments. Just flags.